# Mirror/Symmetry effect on video using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, mirror, symmetry

I want to create a basic video editing application where the user can import video clips and then use symmetry (vertical or horizontal) and offsets on their videos. How feasible is this?

For instance, consider the following image:

[image]

Right-symmetry:

[image]

Image offset to the top-left:

[image]

If that last image is confusing, basically you can think of it as the images repeating one next to the the other in a grid, infinitely, such that they're symmetric. Then, you can select a window of this grid equal to the size of the original image. Eg. the red square represents the window:

[image]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I suppose if there's a simple way to achieve the offset

Answer (score 0):

This is very feasible. Opencv can do all of this frame by frame. Although it would probably take sometime for high quality/long videos. If you want to know how to do these operations, I would open seperate questions. mirroring can for example be done by `cv2.flip()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.flip ()` method present in the cv2 library. First enter the image with `cv2.imread (path)`. Then to make the mirror effect you have to create a insert `cv2.flip (image, 0)`.
Just as reported below:

```
image = cv2.imread(path) 
mirrow = cv2.flip(image, 0)
```

Comment: You can do the same thing with videos of course